# Node list is empty when getting img from page

Tags: php, goutte

I am using `"fabpot/goutte": "^4.0",` and would like to get the image from the following page:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;


$content = $client->request('GET', "https://www.laststicker.com/cards/panini_fifa_womens_world_cup_2019/1/")->html();
$crawler = new Crawler($content, null, null);

$imgUrls = [];
$crawler->filter('#content > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > img')->each(function ($link) use (&$imgUrls) {
    array_push($imgUrls, $link->attr('src'));
});
```

I get: `The current node list is emtpy`

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?